# PHP Includes/Require in a function with variable for path

Tags: php, global-variables, require

I am trying to set things up so when we create a testing folder, I can easily change the path to an important file in various places. But, running into an issue.

```
$folder = "/test";

function foo(){
global $folder;
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$folder."/order/includes/db.php");
..do stuff

}
```

Does not work

```
function foo(){
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/test/includes/db.php");
..do stuff
}
```

Does work

What am I missing?

Comment: /order/ is missing in the second snippet (the working one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the global $folder; from your function foo() and it shall work.
Another alternative is adding the keyword global to your declaration:

```
$folder = "/test";

function foo(){
    require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$folder."/order/includes/db.php");
    ..do stuff

}
```

OR

```
global $folder = "/test";

function foo(){
global $folder;
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$folder."/order/includes/db.php");
..do stuff

}
```

Comment: global $folder = "/test" through me an error but calling global $folder after the far was fine. I also found that require_once was an issue in that it had been called before and therefore was not giving me the variables in the include file. Using just require fixed that issue